# Concatenate a list of POSIXct vectors

Tags: r, datetime

Suppose you have a list, and each element of the list is a POSIXct vector, like so:

```
> t = `attr<-`(Sys.time(), "tzone", "UTC")
> t
[1] "2019-10-02 16:07:19 UTC"
> dts = list(t + 1:3, t + 6:9)
> dts
[[1]]
[1] "2019-10-02 16:07:20 UTC" "2019-10-02 16:07:21 UTC"
[3] "2019-10-02 16:07:22 UTC"

[[2]]
[1] "2019-10-02 16:07:25 UTC" "2019-10-02 16:07:26 UTC"
[3] "2019-10-02 16:07:27 UTC" "2019-10-02 16:07:28 UTC"
```

I'd like to concatenate the vectors in `dts`, yielding the same thing as `t + c(1:3, 6:9)`. But `unlist(dts)` and `c(dts, recursive = TRUE)` drop the class and attributes of the elements, returning only ordinary numeric vectors. What do?

For simplicity, we may assume that all POSIXct vectors in the list are in the same time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `do.call` with `c` to avoid coercing it to `numeric`

```
do.call(c, dts)
#[1] "2019-10-02 12:11:33 EDT" "2019-10-02 12:11:34 EDT" "2019-10-02 12:11:35 EDT" "2019-10-02 12:11:38 EDT" "2019-10-02 12:11:39 EDT" "2019-10-02 12:11:40 EDT"
#[7] "2019-10-02 12:11:41 EDT"
```

---

Or with `reduce` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
reduce(dts, c)
```

Comment: Or even base R:  `Reduce(c, dts)`